# Multiple IDs for one AltID

Tags: sql

I have three tables that each have an `Altid` - I want to match each table on `Altid` and return each `ID` that does not match

example:

```
table a    Altindx                      600650                3970034000
                                        602469                4300221000
                                        611183                5012600000
                                        612415                2002501930

table b    Datindx                      600650                3970034001
                                        602469                4300221000
                                        611183                5012600000
                                        612415                2002501931

table c    Mtindx                       600650                3970034002
                                        602469                4300221001
                                        611183                5012600000
                                        612415                2002501930
```

the data sorted by altid

```
a       600650                3970034000
b       600650                3970034001
c       600650                3970034002

a       602469                4300221000    
b       602469                4300221000
c       602469                4300221001

a       611183                5012600000
b       611183                5012600000
c       611183                5012600000

a       612415                2002501930
b       612415                2002501931
c       612415                2002501930
```

The report should look like this:

```
600650                   3970034000
                         3970034001
                         3970034002

602469                   4300221000 
                         4300221001

612415                   2002501930
                         2002501931
```

`611183` - should not appear on the report as all the `ID`s match

Comment: Relational division: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29

Comment: It could be relevant what flavor of SQL you are using, and if you have tried anything, let us know more about that.

Answer (score 0):

you have two field, if assume one is `id` and two is `value`, SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT id, value FROM altindex
    UNION
    SELECT id, value FROM latindex
    UNION
    SELECT id, value FROM mtindex
) index
ORDER BY index.id ASC, index.value ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

This unions all of the tables together then counts how many times each AltID, ID pair occurs. Pairs that occur 3 times are excluded from the results, since that implies that the pair exists in all three tables.

```
select AltID, ID
from (
    select AltID, ID from Altindx
    union all
    select AltID, ID from Datindx
    union all
    select AltID, ID from Mtindx
) x 
group by AltID, ID
having COUNT('') < 3
order by AltID, ID
```

Comment: Answers should always have some kind of explanation instead of 'just' code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Value FROM 
(
  SELECT A as T, ID, Value
  FROM altindex
  UNION ALL
  SELECT B as T, ID, Value 
  FROM latindex
  UNION ALL
  SELECT C as T, ID, Value 
  FROM mtindex
) sublist
WHERE
  COUNT(T) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, VALUE) > 1
```